# DOUBLE_WHITESPACE in PATH error

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

i am learning JSTL and from tutorials point in [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm)
when i tried to execute that example in the page which is

```
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
     <html>
     <head>
     <title><c:url> Tag Example</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <a href="<c:url value="/jsp/index.htm"/>">TEST</a>
     </body>
     </html>
```

i am getting following error.[image: error pic]

but i could not understand why and what is the solution for that?

Comment: Looks like your c:url call is returning empty spaces.  Do any other tags give you the output you expect?

Comment: except for href="new.jsp", every time it's same error.

Answer (score 1):

The validator is probably confused by the nested double quotes:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/jsp/index.htm"/>">TEST</a>
```

You can make the code cleaner by doing:

```
<c:url value="/jsp/index.htm" var="myUrl" />
<a href="${myUrl}">TEST</a>
```

which assigns the value of the processed URL to a var named 'myUrl' and then uses JSP Expression language to output the URL.

Comment: thanks for help. but its not working. i guess it has problem with ' { ' . i am using netbeans 7.2 does it have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```html
<title><c:url> Tag Example</title>
```

By:

```html
<title>&LT;c:url&GT; Tag Example</title>
```

Otherwise, the JSP engine will interpret this (`<c:url>`) as the beginning of a tag to be processed.

Comment: error didn't disappear. its still there. i am going mad with this error. its simple example.

Comment: That error does not appear in NetBeans 8.0.2. In the best of cases, simply ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your nested quotes as

```
<a href="<c:url value=\"/jsp/index.htm\"/>">TEST</a>
```

Otherwise the HTML parser perceives `"<c:url value="` as the `href` value and complains about the space in between. Alternatively, you can make use of single and double quotes as

```
<a href='<c:url value="/jsp/index.htm"/>'>TEST</a>
```

Or,

```
<a href="<c:url value='/jsp/index.htm'/>">TEST</a>
```

Comment: thanks for help, but none of it worked. same error popping up for every solution. i am using netbeans 7.2. does it have anything to do with it?